# Not setting value to <form:textarea> tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using this code to set data to textarea but no value is setting to 
 text area. I am using Spring 5. Need help.`<form:textarea path="description" value="${termMaster.description}" rows="3" cols="2" class="span11" placeholder="Description:"></form:textarea>`

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Isn't textarea defined as `<fm:textarea>${termMaster.description}</fm:textarea>` like this?

Comment: @SajalGupta I guess Spring 5 does not allow to have declaration like <fm:textarea>${termMaster.description}</fm:textarea>. Older versions allow this but not in new versions of springs. Doing so shows an error <fm:textarea> tag must be empty.

Comment: oh ok. I know Spring 4. I thought it must be same as before. Sorry!

Comment: @SajalGupta Ok. Thanks. If you find the solution. Please do let me know.